# React Native Firebase | Turn child values into Lists

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

so im trying to get the child values from Firebase and then put it on array then show it as a list, but i can't get it to work.

I used ReactNative Elements Lists for showing the list.

Here's my code

```
const list = [];                                                        
export default class ContactPerson extends Component<Props> {
readData() {
    firebase.database().ref('contactperson').on('value', function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
            var data = childSnapshot.val();
            list.push(data);
        });
    });
}
componentDidMount() {
    this.readData();
}
renderRow ({ item }) {
    return (
        <ListItem
            roundAvatar
            title={item.nama}
            subtitle={item.no_hp}
            avatar={{uri:item.image_url}}
        />
    )
}
render () {
    return (
        <List>
            <FlatList
                data={list}
                renderItem={this.renderRow}
                keyExtractor={item => item.nama}
            />
        </List>
    )
}}
```

And then the Firebase Database structure : 
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWMNU.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the item to the method creating single element as following

```
renderRow (item) {
   return (
    <ListItem
        roundAvatar
        title={item.nama}
        subtitle={item.no_hp}
        avatar={{uri:item.image_url}}
    />
)}
render () {
  return (
    <List>
        <FlatList
          data={list}
          renderItem={(item) => this.renderRow(item)}
          keyExtractor={item => item.nama}
        />
    </List>
  )
}}
```

please refer the [documentation for flatlist](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist)